# how refresh token concept works if the token expires once user post http request

Tags: asp.net-core, jwt

I have implemented JWT authentication in asp.net core web api and front end is reactjs
we need to implement the sliding expiration for the session.

But I am not getting a flow explained from the front end perspective

If the user submit a http post request with the data from reactjs frontend and if the token expires?
how this is handled?

or every time if it api needs to check the token validity ? will it be a costly resource intensive check?

I am not able to find any blog explaining from the frontend perspective.

I can see people are explaining using post man , if it expires how to get a new one ? like that

Thanks,

Comment: it should be handle by your react app. the usual recommended way is to have a function that keeps track on token expiry when sending request to backend and send refresh token request when the expiry is almost over .

Answer (score 0):

Suppose we are talking about an HTTP service. You could introduce two tokens, a short-lived token and a long-lived one.

If the short-lived token was expired, then the backend should return 401. In this case, the client-side could ask for a new short-lived token by requesting your backend with the long-lived token.
If the long-lived token was expired, then you need to authenticate app user.

If you only want to use a short-lived token, then when it is expired, the frontend needs to send an authentication request to the backend with app user credential.

You have to verify JWT every time to ensure JWT integrity.

You could refer to Google Firebase Authentication Service, Okta, Auth0.